# Kafka consumer for multiple topis using Confluent's .NET API

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have a consumer that needs to consume messages from multiple topics from multiple producers. I am using Confluent's .NET API in both my producer and Consumer. My consumer is able to consume messages just fine when subscribed to a single topic. However, when subscribed to multiple topics, I am unable to consume any messages. I have tried two approaches for subscribing to multiple topics, the first of which is using Consumer.subscribe(List). In the second approach, I tried to subscribe to each topic one at a time in a loop. Unfortunately, this did not work either. How can I consume from multiple topics successfully using the Confluent .NET API?

Comment: Is new data coming to the topic? May be you can try `auto.offset.reset=earliest` in the consumer configuration or even try changing the `group.id` (in case if the messages are already consumed by some other consumer or this consumer previously)

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.